# Jquery autocomplete gridview row select

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, autocomplete

I have an auto complete jQuery `gridview` which will filter when I type in `textbox`. I want to select anywhere in the row and pass row Id to session. 
How can I do it? below is my code.

JavaScript:

```
$("#popup").ready(function () {
   GetCustomers(1);
});
$("[id*=txtSearch]").live("keyup", function () {
   GetCustomers(parseInt(1));
});
$(".Pager .page").live("click", function () {
   GetCustomers(parseInt($(this).attr('page')));
});
function SearchTerm() {
   return jQuery.trim($("[id*=txtSearch]").val());
};
function GetCustomers(pageIndex) {
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Home.aspx/GetCustomers",
       data: '{searchTerm: "' + SearchTerm() + '", pageIndex: ' + pageIndex +       '}',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: OnSuccess,
       failure: function (response) {
           alert(response.d);
       },
       error: function (response) {
           alert(response.d);
       }
  });
}
var row;
function OnSuccess(response) {
   var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
   var xml = $(xmlDoc);
   var customers = xml.find("Customers");
   if (row == null) {
       row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
   }
   $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr").not($("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:first-child")).remove();
   if (customers.length > 0) {
       $.each(customers, function () {
          var customer = $(this);
          //$("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("Id").text());
          $("td", row).eq(0).html($(this).find("Patient_First_Name").text());
          $("td", row).eq(1).html($(this).find("Patient_DOB").text());
          $("td", row).eq(2).html($(this).find("Patient_Home_Phone").text());
          $("td", row).eq(3).html($(this).find("Patient_Account_No").text());

          $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(row);
          row = $("[id*=gvCustomers] tr:last-child").clone(true);
      });
    var pager = xml.find("Pager");
    $(".Pager").ASPSnippets_Pager({
        ActiveCssClass: "current",
        PagerCssClass: "pager",
        PageIndex: parseInt(pager.find("PageIndex").text()),
        PageSize: parseInt(pager.find("PageSize").text()),
        RecordCount: parseInt(pager.find("RecordCount").text())
    });

    $(".ContactName").each(function () {
        var searchPattern = new RegExp('(' + SearchTerm() + ')', 'ig');
        $(this).html($(this).text().replace(searchPattern, "<span class = 'highlight'>" + SearchTerm() + "</span>"));
    });
   } else {
    var empty_row = row.clone(true);
    $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("colspan", $("td", row).length);
    $("td:first-child", empty_row).attr("align", "center");
    $("td:first-child", empty_row).html("No records found for the search criteria.");
    $("td", empty_row).not($("td:first-child", empty_row)).remove();
    $("[id*=gvCustomers]").append(empty_row);
  }
};
```

aspx:-

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" CssClass="gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvCustomers_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
      <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />--%>
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Patient_First_Name" HeaderText="First Name" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Patient_DOB" HeaderText="Dob" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Patient_Home_Phone" HeaderText="Phone Number" />
      <asp:BoundField DataField="Patient_Account_No" HeaderText="Account No" />
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="test" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Patient_First_Name", "show.aspx?ID={0}") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
         </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

C#:-

```
    protected void gvCustomers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "this.style.cursor='pointer';this.style.textDecoration='underline';this.style.backgroundColor='#81DAF5';";
            e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] = "this.style.textDecoration='none';this.style.backgroundColor='#FFFFFF';";
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(new System.Web.UI.PostBackOptions(this.gvCustomers, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Suggestion: why dont you use `jQueryUI Autocomplete` for your problem. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: yes, but i want filter data in gridview not in single textbox. i searched the lot in the internet and above code is closest i can get.. it is working fine. but only i cannot able to select any rows.